# How to "enter" in google colab when code is executing

Tags: google-colaboratory

This question has been asked in two places that I see and it doesn't give the answer.  One is for anaconda and the upvoted answer says to install it in a certain but doesn't answer it so here goes:

I execute this in a cell:

```
!add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
!apt-get update
!apt-get install python3.6
!apt-get install python3.6-dev

!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.6 get-pip.py

import sys

sys.path[2] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[7] ='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
```

Does an install and I get this:

```
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
```

Enter is not recognized when clicked on the keyboard.  How can I hit "enter" on the code running?

Answer (score 2):

From all the questions regarding this none gave away to achieve this.
Most ask that you receive an input with print but if you are running a package then this would be a lot more tedious.

What I ended up doing was installing a terminal called colab-xterm

Thanks to a cool little post I found by Dave Flynn.
I install like so:

```
!pip install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm
```

Then I executed the terminal like so:

```
%xterm
```

The terminal opens in jupyter notebook and I am able to input into the terminal command.

Also on some instances if "yes" or "no" is required you can add it as a flag.  In example

```
! conda install opencv -y
```

The yes can be prepopulated with -y